# Neo4j SET (update) node properties error

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I'm trying to SET (update) a Neo4j using JavaScript. I'm using the JavaScript language drivers.

My code executes but the node properties do not update.

Here is my code:

```
        return session.run("MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.ID = {id} SET a.name = {name}, a.email = {email}", {
            id: 114,
            name: name,
            email: email
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript numbers are 32 bit, Neo4j's are 64 bit, there's some conversion you'll need to perform when setting or retrieving numeric data.

Here's the [relevant section](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#write-integers) on this in the driver readme. The number being passed gets converted into a float, so you need to pass the number through `neo4j.int()` to force it to an int type like so:

```
return session.run("MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.ID = {id} SET a.name = {name}, a.email = {email}", {
            id: neo4j.int(114),
            name: name,
            email: email
        });
```