# update using ID(n) cypher + JS

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

If ask for change the value of `n.nombre` using the number of the `ID` like this, works fine

```
    session 
.run(
"MATCH(n) WHERE ID(n)=0 SET n.nombre={elemento}",{elemento:elemento});
session.close();
```

But if I use the variable `node` (with value 0) I do not get any change, do you know why?

```
    session 
    .run(
    "MATCH(n) WHERE ID(n)={node} SET n.nombre={elemento}",{elemento:elemento, node:node});  
     session.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43216272/92359).

You need to use `neo4j.int()` when wrapping numeric integer values for use in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks InverseFalcon. Other way to convert the value to an integer is using `toInt()`

```
 session 
.run(
"MATCH(n) WHERE ID(n)=toInt({node}) SET n.nombre={elemento}",{elemento:elemento, node:node});  
 session.close();
```